# Cleaning directories ending in `.js`

Tags: gruntjs

I am writing a grunt task to clean out unneeded bower files. however, I'm having a difficult time getting it to play nice with `Chart.js` since the directory itself ends in `.js`.

This is what I currently have, but it is not working (it's still deleting the entire directory `Chart.js` when in reality I want it to only delete files):

```
bower: {
    src: [
        '!build/bower_components/**/*.min.js',
        '!build/bower_components/Chart.js/',
        'build/bower_components/**/*.js'
    ]
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Why not rename the directory?

Comment: What happens if you try `'!build/bower_components/**'` or `'!build/bower_components/*.js'`?

Comment: @DavidT That second one worked beautifully, actually. Also, my main problem was the ordering (the `!` statements need to come at the end, not the beginning)

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. I have written the comments up into an answer. Id be grateful if you found it useful to upvote/mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments under the actual question, trying `'!build/bower_components/*.js'` would seem to fix the problem.

My guess is that it is simply matching the glob its using to match against strings as directory structures. And `Chart.js` matches `../*.js` regardless of it being a directory.

Also as you mention yourself in the comments - putting the `!` (not) directory strings at the bottoms also helps.